# C Project - two libraries use same typedef identifier for different types

Tags: c, typedef

I'm working on a project using the MODBUS2 lib, and I want to add the FatFs lib to it to interface with an SD card. Both libraries use identifier `SHORT` for `short` and `int` respectively, and the compiler throws this error:

```
#258 invalid redeclaration of type name "SHORT"
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: either make it a common include, or rename one of the SHORT idents. Is that a typedef?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add relevant details (i.e. code)

Comment: trick answer: use better libraries, that don't do such ugly things. `typedef`ing `SHORT` as `int`, really?

Comment: ...These libraries might as well `#define if else` while they're at it.

Comment: Place the #include for the header files in different source files,  Then each source file only accesses the functions in the related header file.

Answer (score 7):

You need to restructure your project in such a way that no translation unit of your library would have to include headers from both libraries (translation unit is a fancy name for a C file).

One approach is to write your own thin "wrapper" functions around MODBUS2 and FatFs functionality. Each wrapper would have to include headers for the library that it wraps, so there would be no compile-time collision. Then the main module of your library would program to your "wrappers", without including MODBUS2 or FatFs headers at all.

Comment: "_fancy name for a C file_" ... I like that :)

Comment: @machine_1 Except it isn't. The translation unit may be organized around a C file, but it consists of all the material from the include files also.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose library 1 has

```
typedef int SHORT;
```

and library 2 has

```
typedef short SHORT;
```

Suppose you have this code:

```
#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"
```

You might be able to fix the compilation error like this:

```
#define SHORT LIB1_SHORT
#include "lib1.h"
#undef SHORT
#define SHORT LIB2_SHORT
#include "lib2.h"
#undef SHORT
```

If you do this, you should do it consistently for all `#include` directives in your code. If you don't have too many `#include`s, this is not too tedious.

If you don't want to keep these rules in mind all the time, stuff the `#define` and `#undef` as first and last thing in all problematic library headers.

Comment: If you're going to go down this route, put the code you show in a new header file, and where you include both library headers, replace the two lines of code with a single include of your composite file.  Then, when there are another pair of collisions after the next release of one of the libraries, you only have one file to edit.  Beware "boiled frog" syndrome: you have one collision now; it is 'simple' to patch the 20 files, so you add the preprocessor magic to each file. Then the new version comes out, and you go and patch the 20 files again. Rinse and repeat; it gets worse over time.

Answer (score 1):

The libraries which use those `SHORT` typedefs without any prefix are ill-designed, since there are no namespaces in C, so they're strongly constraining the users. Ok, but we have to live with that.

If the typedefs were defining the same type, there would be no problem as you can repeat:

```
typedef int SHORT;
typedef int SHORT;
```

as many times you want as long as it defines the same base type. But here the types are different, so that's the issue.

One hack would be to use a "word-only" replace on all of the FatFs library includes/sources for instance to replace `SHORT` by `FF_SHORT`.

now you can include both libraries without any conflict.

- main advantage: no need for more changes or wrappers (like the superior other answer suggests): quick & dirty.
- main drawback: must be done at each upgrade of the library interface.

Comment: Note that repeating a `typedef` without error requires C11 support.